# Use an outer While Loop that is sentinel driven to ask the user if they wish to generate a new set of random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, do-while, sentinel

This is what I have so far but for some reason the program states the operation is complete without allowing the user to enter 1 or 2 to continue or not. Thanks in advance..

My code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public final class Kidwell_Lab09 {
    public static Random generator = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;

        int[] randomNumbers = new int[20];

        do
        {
            Random generator = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++){
                int n = generator.nextInt(10)+1;
                randomNumbers[i] = n;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
            }
            System.out.print("Do you wish to restart the program, Enter 1 for YES, 2              for NO: ");
            x = generator.nextInt();
        }
        while ( x == 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're writing prompt to stdout, but not reading user response from stdin, so program prints prompt and keeps going

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ debugging your own code is a good skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be reading the value from System.in rather than from generator.nextInt().

Here is the corrected code.

```
import java.util.Random;
public final class Kidwell_Lab09 {
    public static Random generator = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;

        int[] randomNumbers = new int[20];
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            Random generator = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
                int n = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
                randomNumbers[i] = n;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
            }
            System.out.print("Do you wish to restart the program, Enter 1 for YES, 2              for NO: ");            
            x = inputReader.nextInt();
        } while (x == 1);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the timely response and help. Makes a lot more sense now...sometimes just another set of eyes is needed!

Comment: @kidbone222 if the answer is correct and useful for you please accept the answer

Comment: @ Raghu K Nair, I am receiving an error message now : Kidwell_Lab09.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Kidwell_Lab09
Kidwell_Lab09.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Kidwell_Lab09

Comment: you have to add "import java.util.Scanner;"  in the import section

Comment: That was a dumb question and I apologize, have been working on this for quite some time. While I have your attention..may I ask one more question? I understand that when you put something in an array for 20 like I have that it will print out 0-19, is there anyway to make it print it out 1-20? Thanks @ Raghu K Nair